# Proof of an $\frac{a}b=\frac{c}d⟺\frac{a+b}{a−b}=\frac{c+d}{c−d}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I'm trying to prove this : 
$\frac{a}b=\frac{c}d⟺\frac{a+b}{a−b}=\frac{c+d}{c−d}$

but going from $\frac{a}b=\frac{c}d$

I already proved it backwards

$\frac{a+b}{a−b}=\frac{c+d}{c−d}$
I multiply each side by (a-b)(c-d)

$ac-ad+bc-bd = ac - bc + ad - bd$
so $2bc=2ad$
which by dividing both sides by $2bd$ gives us :
$$\frac{a}b=\frac{c}d$$

any ideas how to proceed ?

Edit : this equivalence only works when $a\neq b $ and $c \neq d$.

Comment: You want to know how to go from $\frac ab = \frac cd$ to $\frac{a-b}{a+b} = \frac{c-d}{c+d}$? I just want to clarify what you want.

Comment: yes and sorry for being unclear

Comment: My friend it's ok to be unclear at times.

Comment: @1.2.3 Equivalence relations is not a correct tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $a \neq b, c\neq d$, and $b,d \neq 0$. Then, $\frac ab \neq 1$. We are asked to assume that $\frac ab =  \frac cd$.

Now, we can do the following:

$$
\frac ab = \frac cd \implies \frac ab + 1 = \frac cd + 1  \implies \frac{a+b}b = \frac{c+d}d\\
\frac ab = \frac cd \implies \frac ab - 1 = \frac cd - 1 \implies \frac{a-b}{b} = \frac{c-d}{d}\\
$$

Divide the first equation by the second:
$$
\frac{\frac{a+b}{b}}{\frac{a-b}b} = \frac{\frac{c+d}d}{\frac{c-d}d} \implies \frac{a+b}{a-b} = \frac{c+d}{c-d}
$$

This is a proof, provided the conditions that are given in the starting hold true.

On a side note, I think this is called the componendo-dividendo equality (I may be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I do not think the two statements are equivalent. Take $a=b=c=d=1$ then your first equality holds while the second on is undefined.

Comment: yes I forgot to mention that the trick fails for a=b and c=d.
thanks for reminding

Comment: -1;This is not an answer but more of a comment.

Comment: @A---B Somewhat agree and certainly +1 for explaining the downvote. On the other hand the question is 'I am trying to prove this claim' and I answer 'This claim is false'.

Comment: Yes you are right in a way but this was pretty trivial that OP forgot to mention.