# Why $\frac {a}{b} = \frac {c}{d} \implies \frac {a+c}{b+d} = \frac {a}{b} = \frac {c}{d}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

In geometry class, this property was quickly introduced:

> $$\dfrac {a}{b} = \dfrac {c}{d} \implies \dfrac {a+c}{b+d} = \dfrac {a}{b} = \dfrac {c}{d} $$

It usually avoids some boring quadratic equations, so it's useful but I don't really get it. Seems trivial but I can't prove.

How to demonstrate it?

Comment: That is generally untrue.  For counterexample, consider $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{5}{6}\neq \frac{2}{5}=\frac{1+1}{2+3}$.  Instead what is actually true is $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad+cb}{bd}$

Comment: This is not true @rodorgas. Take the L.C.M. and solve is simply you will got $ad^2+cb^2=0$ which is not given or true.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm sorry I typed it wrong. Please see my updated and corrected question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of an $\frac{a}b=\frac{c}d⟺\frac{a+b}{a−b}=\frac{c+d}{c−d}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154300/proof-of-an-fracab-fraccd%e2%9f%ba-fracaba%e2%88%92b-fraccdc%e2%88%92d)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\Rightarrow\frac{a+c}{b+d}=\frac{a+\frac{ad}{b}}{b+d}=\frac{ab+ad}{b(b+d)}=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that none of the unknowns is zero.
Then, let
$$\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}=k$$
This implies,
$$ a=kb,\qquad c=kd$$

$$\therefore{a+c}=k(b+d)$$
$$\implies \dfrac{a+c}{b+d}=k$$

Comment: I believe you mean `(a+c)/(b+d)` in the last expression. Nice method, though! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\frac{p}{q} = \frac{r}{s}
$$
if and only if $ps = rq$.